How to analyze opposite predictive effects in high vs. low depression groups？
I hypothesize that in low-depression and high-depression groups (this grouping is based on depression PHQ9 levels and is a dichotomous variable), emotion A's predictive effect on depression would be opposite. Specifically, in the low-depression group, emotion A negatively predicts depression levels (which is a continuous variable), while in the high-depression group, emotion A positively predicts depression levels. I want to compare the relationship between emotion A and depression under these two groupings. What analytical methods can I use to conduct such analysis?

If I use regression analysis, such as lm(), I can conduct regression analyses separately in low-depression and high-depression groups to test emotion A's predictive effect on depression levels, and then use coeftest() to compare the regression coefficients between the two groups.

If I treat depression grouping as a moderating variable, I can examine the interaction effect between depression grouping and emotion A. However, I'm confused about whether it's appropriate to have a moderating variable that comes from or is highly correlated with the dependent variable, since the depression grouping is derived from depression scores.


